# How do I get Kotlin to Work in Sublime Text?

Tags: kotlin, sublimetext3

I followed a tutorial from GitHub on how to get it to work but whenever I try to run the code is comes back with:

```
'kotlinc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 31ms]
```

I tried to redo everything and even went as far as to uninstall sublime text and starting from scratch but the same error comes up, Any help is highly appreciated I know it may be a pretty basic question but I'm pretty new to all this.

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Kotlin

Comment: Did you install Kotlin? Builds in Sublime run external tools, but it's up to you to install what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Click on "Tools" -> "Build with" -> "Kotlin Compile + Run"

Comment: Ensure you set "Build System->" to "Automatic"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).